# mvc httppost does pop out iframe using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iframe, partial-views

I'm having some issues loading a partial page on an iframe. I finally got the chance to have no errors but it's not laoding the partial page. Here's the code:

```
function formPostComplete(data) {
        var pcode = '<%: Model.pcode %>';
        console.log('efrid = ' + data.EfrId);
        var efrId = data.EfrId;
        var eid = data.EventId;
        var href = '<%: Url.Action("Detail", "Events") %>?pname=' + pcode + '&eid=' + eid + '&efrId=' + efrId;

        console.log('href ' + href);
        var iframe = $('<iframe id="iframe-divisions" width:"500" height="300" style="display:none;"></iframe>');
        $(document.body).append(iframe);
        $('iframe#iframe-divisions').attr('src', href);
        iframe.load(function () {

            alert('supposed to be loaded!!');
            console.log('function end');
        });
    };
```

This is the Form part

```
Ajax.BeginForm('Create', new AjaxOptions() {
       OnSuccess = "formPostComplete"}){
            :
            :
       textboxes and then submit
            :
}
```

This is what the Create (httppost) returns after doing the transaction:

```
return Json(new { Success = true, EventId = search.Eid, EfrId = search.EfrId });
```

This is what the "Detail" method returns after the iframe is created and "supposed" to be loading the page, it's a partial view

```
public ActionResult Detail(int eid, int efrid, string pcode){

List<Participant> mymodel = new List<Participant>();
mymodel = Participant.LoadParticipants(context, eid);

return PartialView(mymodel);
}
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: your iframe is created with style "display:none" . I don't see anything in your code that makes it visible after that.

Comment: oh shite! i didn't see, i copied it from my other project. let me see if that will work when i get home later. thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @jbl ok that worked. now just trying to figure out how to pop it out like a dialog box

Comment: I think you should rely on some third-party component for that (like jquery.UI Dialog) This should save you a lot of time :-)

Comment: do u think i can load a partial view into that? im loading it after posting..